# Multithreading socket output stream communication

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, outputstream

I have my android tablet, (server) and I have my samsung S3 (client 1), and Samsung S4 (client 2) I have them both connect (or maybe not I created a new thread per connection that came in) to my tablet (server), I have them in a listview, and I created a menu and when I tapped on the listview it would bring the menu up and it would send command to the last connected device (client 2) even though I tapped on client 1.

How can I have it to where I can communicate with client 1, and client 2 separately from each other? Do I need to switch the outputstream? (is that even a thing?) do I need to use the ip and port to respond back? (again is that even a thing?)

I hope someone will be able to help me with this.

edit; This isn't a listview problem because I do not know what coding on sockets I would have to do to communicate back to clients separate from each other.

Comment: In general, sockets on the server look like this: `newclientsock = listensock.accept()` Now you use `newclientsock` to communicate with that client. Often times, each client socket is handled in its own thread (although this is not required, see `select`).

Comment: Any example code? if netclientsock was used on every connection wouldn't it be like asking for bob in a room and everybody was named bob?

Comment: just search for "socket programming java", there are thousands of results.  When you call `accept`, you're saying "wait for a new connection", and the result of that call is a new socket, identifying the connection between you and the specific client that connected. There's zero ambiguity in the socket.

Comment: I must be asking for the impossible to be honest. I appreciate the help, but  I still don't understand. Like I said, i have gone through pages of google search results. Even with java examples. None of them specify how to identify each socket connection so you can communicate with that specific one.

Comment: Removed several yards of irrelevant waffle from this question.

Answer (score 0):

The examples here are derived from [Writing the Server Side of a Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) (oracle.com). I *strongly* suggest you work through that example code ASAP.  It would be **far** easier to do this locally on your PC, before you go about involving multiple wireless devices. (I never understood why people try to bite off so much more than they can chew, then get frustrated and give up.... Learn to walk before you run!)

```
/**
  * Create a new server socket. This represents a TCP socket
  * in the LISTENING state, which means it is waiting for clients
  * to connect. It is not associated with any client.
  */
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

/**
 * Wait for a client to connect. This call will block (not return)
 * until a client successfully connects to the server.
 */
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

/**
 * Whereas `serverSocket` represents the LISTENING socket, we
 * now have a `clientSocket`, which represents a single ESTABLISHED
 * connection with *a specific client*.
 */

/* Use this to receive data from the client... */
clientSocket.getInputStream();

/* ... or this to send data to the client. */
clientSocket.getOutputStream();

/**
 * At this point, the server is not yet ready for any new connections
 * from new clients. We can choose to either:
 *  o Handle this single connected clientSocket now, and deal with other
 *    clients when we're finished with this one. 
 *  o Spawn a new thread to handle this clientSocket
 *
 * Either way, we must go back to the top, and try to `accept`
 * another connection.
 */
```

Comment: Johanthon I am sorry, I already know about that. and I do it locally on my network. after some more research, I think I can explain it better, essentially how can I make unique identifier for each connected socket? I read something like using hashtable or using GUID, and someone said you can use device ID and timestamp to generate ID for it, so I can send commands to that specific device.